# Controlling Word 2016 from VBA code using SendKeys

Tags: vba, ms-word, sendkeys, office-automation

The problem: In my environment (64-bit Windows 10) I have tens of thousands of old-format Word documents (.doc) that must be updated to the new .docx format. These documents are spread across thousands of folders on a share drive. I have found some code that can automate this process, but it relies on methods in the Word object model that security policies won't allow.

In the Trust Center, under "File Block Settings", I have word 6.0, word 95, word 97 and word 2000 documents blocked. No way to change these -- settings are managed by my organization.

That said, even though I can't open them using VBA, I can manually open some of these doc files. I'm thinking that a really old-school approach might work: Open a blank Word application, then use send-keys to open the doc files and then save in the new docx format.

I can start Word in VBA

```
Dim objWordApplication as Word.Application
set objWordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objectWordApplication.Visible = True
```

**My specific questions**: Once the Word object is running, what do I "send" to it to get it to open a file named xyz.doc? That is, in the following code, what is "ABC"?

`objWordApplication.SendKeys ("ABCxyz", true)`

FYSA, my environment is very strictly controlled. Solutions that invoke any third-party programs, changes to security settings, and other "non-vanilla" actions just won't fly. Finally, for some reason my questions seem like "homework" to some people, so I assure everyone that this is a production-level problem, not homework.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The main problem is that `SendKeys` is never going to be reliable. Any solution you come up using it is going to constantly break. If it is your only option, then at least expect constant problems.

Comment: Understood! I've been tearing my hair out with "reliable" approaches that die because of the security policies. This isn't meant to be a long-term solution. If I can get it working for a couple of days I will be happy.

Comment: Which Word method is "not allowed"?

Comment: I've discovered that using Shell(winword.exe) will create an instance of Word. Using AppActivate makes it the current window. SendKeys "%O" gets me to the file open window, but I cannot get to the "browse" dialog. I can use keyboard keys, but as soon as I turn those into sendkeys statements it breaks. I've even put a 1-second sleep delay between characters.

Comment: I have tried 
set objWordDocument = objWordApplivcation.documents.open(Filename:="Path\Name" plus variations of the aruguments. This works as long as the policies don't get in the way.

Comment: So what error does it give you (not using sendkeys)? Did you try `documents.add` instead of open? (do not use `Shell`)

Comment: It's not that the method is disallowed. The method works fine.  But when trying to open certain older files the policies kick in and prevent the method from completing,

Comment: I will try documents.add tomorrow -- I'm out of time today.  BTW, I appreciate the warnings about Shell -- but if the only way to get to Oregon is to ride through hostile Sioux Indian territory, that's the way I will go.

Comment: If you are open to any other ideas, I would look into finding some freeware that can just batch convert all the doc files to docx not using something like VBA. If "you only need it to work for one hour" then this might be a decent alternative. If you wonder why those old types are blocked, it is because they can contain malicious VBA - Also, it is unlikely that you are going to find someone here to go thru `SendKeys` ideas with you. (not impossible, just unlikely)

Comment: If I get a trappable error, it is 6304 (system policy block), 5174 (system can't find the file, even though it's clearly present) or 5151 (corrupt file). Right now I'm only dealing with the 6304 errors.

Comment: As I mentioned in the opening post, freeware is not an option. My system is locked down. I even have to use a separate computer to make these posts.

Comment: Can you use a separate computer to convert the files just once? Might be your only option. But yes, check back tomorrow. Maybe someone else will know some SendKeys tricks.

Comment: Maybe you can punt this up to your IT organization and have one of them do it?  They are responsible for your security policies, so they should be able to offer solutions when a valid business need conflicts with those policies.

Comment: You might be able to overcome those limitations via the .InsertFile method, or via the use of INCLUDETEXT fields, either of which will allow you to import formatted content into a new, target, document from the source documents without opening them.